# upstairs furnace stopped working after connecting c-wires to both HVACs for ecobee 4 downstairs

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

My AC/heater for upstairs rooms used to work. But after connecting the c-wires to both HVACs in the attic it can no longer be started with the LED controller. I probably should have connected only one of the two c-wires, i.e., the one for the downstairs unit (which also controls the corridors upstairs), but thought it was safe to connect both. Is this wrong?

Ironically the downstairs AC/heater used to be difficult to start which motivated us buying the ecobee 4. Now the downstairs one works just fine but upstairs one stopped working.

Thanks a lot.
  Best,
  John

HVAC picture in attic
https://photos.app.goo.gl/Mo2K4P2S2VjtNcqBA

Edit: today I did some more detective work and here are some additional findings.

Installed with ecobee 4 downstairs zone 2 and kept the old Honeywell hz311 thermostat upstairs zone 1. Hooked the c wire for zone 2 on the furnace wire board in the attic. Originally hooked c wire for zone 1 as well but later removed without affecting the ecobee functionality downstairs. Air comes out from the upstairs vent occasionally for a split second (judged by a helium balloon) but for the most part no heating or air upstairs. Tried battery replacement without use. Multimeter suggests continuity between G/O and R wire, but no continuity between other pairs, including no continuity between R and Y.

Comment: What make and model are the air-handlers/furnaces involved here? Can you post their wiring diagrams + photos of the wiring at the thermostat & both air-handlers/furnaces?

Comment: Could you clarify what it means that "HVAC used to be difficult to start" and also whether you're aiming for the ecobee to control upstairs HVAC, downstairs HVAC, or both together/at the same time?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel added the HVAC picture. Not sure if the model is visible here. As you can see, I later connected both blue wires (c-wires) to their respective HVAC sockets.

Comment: @GregHill I replaced HVAC to "AC/heater"; hope this is clearer/more correct. But really AC should stand for both as air conditioning does not mean specifically cold air. Originally I was just aiming for the ecobee to control downstairs, but I recently read it can control multiple HVACs. I would be happy to just control downstairs.

Comment: That HZ311 is a zone board, we'll need much more info about your setup...

Comment: Measure between the R wires of the respective systems.  Is there 0 volts or 48 volts?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica do you mean the r wires of both zones in the attic furnace switchboard?

Comment: The two low voltage terminals on a transformer are R and C. You say the two transformers have their C wires bridged together.   I mean the R wires on the two transformers.  You can measure it at any point along thge wiring that you please.  Really measure all four: RR RC CR CC.  I want to know if any are over 30V.